# TcpClient не подключается через глобальный IP

Tags: c#, сервер, сокет, async-await

Пишу клиент серверное приложение, создаю сокет через TCPClient, в локалке (127.0.0.1 и двумя компами через Wi-Fi точку доступа с IP компьютеров 192.168.1.*) подключается, через Hamachi тоже подключаются клиент с сервером, а по глобальному IP нет((

IP - белый динамический.
Проброс порта сделан в роутере, фаерволе винды и ESET. [PortChecker](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) и 2ip.ru говорят что порт открыт (и более того сервер переходит в чтение после проверки порта).

Прикладываю код:
**СЕРВЕР:**

```
private void GetIPBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServStat.Text = "[Server] Listening...";

        //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        //IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];

        //IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse(IPTB.Text);
        //IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, 1234);

        //tcpListener = TcpListener.Create(1234);
        //tcpListener = new TcpListener(localEndPoint);
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);

        tcpListener.Start();
    }

private async void Listener()
    {
        tcpClient_S = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

        ServStat.Text = "[Server] Client has connected!";
        if (tcpClient_S != null && tcpClient_S.Connected)
        {
            Read(tcpClient_S);
        }
        Listener();
    }
```

**КЛИЕНТ:**

```
private async void Connect()
    {
        tcpClient_C = new TcpClient();

        ClieStat.Text = "[Client] Connecting...";
        //await tcpClient_C.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 1234);

        //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        //IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];

        //Вот тут подаю глобальный IP. "109.62.221.128"
        IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse(IPTB.Text);
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, 1234);

        await tcpClient_C.ConnectAsync(IP, 1234);
        ClieStat.Text = "[Client] Connected to server!";

        Read(tcpClient_C);
    }
```

Постоянно падает с **ошибкой через глобальный IP** - *таймаут подключения* к серверу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что ему еще для счастья нужно, чтобы через публичный IP подключиться? Может что в коде не так?
Заранее спасибо за помощь и ценные советы :)

Comment: По глобальному ай пи можно подключиться, только если клиент снаружи внутренней сети. Т.е. у клиента внешний адрес != Адресу сервера. Иначе на маршрутизаторе нужно колбасить hair pin NAT.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте пропинговать свой внешний адрес. Если пинг полностью пройдет, тогда пробуйте брендмауер отключить полностью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[РЕШЕНО] Спасибо большое Gecube, через подключение с внешнего компьютера (за локальной сетью) на публичный IP запущенного сервера действительно все работает.

Я подключался к глобальному IP из локальной сети, действительно для этого нужно пробрасывать Hairpin NAT.

Comment: Если проблема решена, отметьте ваш ответ зелёной галочкой (слева).